# how to reduce Flutter launch_background.xml display time?

Tags: flutter, frontend, flutter-layout, splash-screen, flutter-animation

I have set an image in launch_background.xml file for splash screen. it takes around 5sec to switch to next page. how to reduce display time.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Modify this file to customize your launch splash screen -->
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <!--   <item android:drawable="@android:color/white" />-->

    <!-- You can insert your own image assets here -->
  <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@mipmap/splash_screen" />
    </item> 
</layer-list>
```

Please suggest how to reduce display time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are running app in debug mode so it will take time. I will suggest you run the app in release mode. by running this command in terminal.

```
flutter run --release
```

> By default, flutter run compiles to debug mode. Your IDE supports this mode. Android Studio, for example, provides a Run > Debug… menu option, as well as a green bug icon overlayed with a small triangle on the project page.

Read more about [Flutter's build modes here](https://flutter.dev/docs/testing/build-modes#debug)